# is it possible to get Oracle SQL Developer to escape output when exporting as inserts?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible, and if so, how, to tell Oracle SQL Developer to escape single quotes whenn exporting a table to inserts? It seems like an obvious thing to want to do, escape the character being used to quote fields when it occurs within the field, but I cannot find the option to do it.

Update: version 2.1.1.64, export method is. Context menu>export data>insert...

Comment: If you don't get the answer here, you might try http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knoow there was one.

Comment: What version of Oracle SQL Developer are you using, and which export option? When I try this in 3.0, the Tools->Database Export correctly escapes the ' characters. (The only thing I find I have to do is add `SET DEFINE ON` at the top of the script to take care of embedded `&` characters in the data.)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it using SQL Developer 3.0.04, and it appears that the single quotes in data are escaped by default:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  File created - Wednesday-June-01-2011   
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table T3
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "THEUSER"."T3" 
   ("C1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "C2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
     PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
     STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
     PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 
     BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
REM INSERTING into THEUSER.T3
Insert into THEUSER.T3 (C1,C2) values ('C1','C''2');
```

I just had one row in the table, consisting of the values C1 and C'2.